# Bottle Counting Program, switch statement inquery, find maximum number

Tags: c#, int, switch-statement, max

my program records the number of bottles that 4 rooms has collected. I am a beginner at C# but have done java in the past.

I shall not use LINQ, I shall not use Arrays. Switch statement only (sorry, i know its inefficient)

My program has to record the number of bottles entered by the user and when the user types "quit" the program is suppose to spit out the bottle count of all rooms and determine the room with the most bottle as the winner.

I'm stuck on this switch statement which I cannot find a way to initiate my rooms (room1, room2, room3, room4), it says variable room1-4 is not assigned. I should be able to continuously add bottle to a room through using the switch.

When i type quit, the program can spit out all the bottles collected by rooms and find the room with the most bottles.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate how much this community has helped me.

```
 namespace BottleDrive1
 {
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {//Initialize 4 rooms. 
        int room1 = 0;

        int room2 = 0;

        int room3 = 0;

        int room4 = 0;
        //Start of while loop to ask what room your adding into. 
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
            //If user enters quit at anytime, the code will jump out of while statement and enter for loop below
            string quit = Console.ReadLine();
            if (quit == "quit")
                //Break statement allows quit to jump out of loop
                break;}}
            private void SetRoom(int room, int value)
            {
            switch (room)
            {
                case 1:
                    room1 = value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    room2 = value;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    room3 = value;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    room4 = value;
                    break;
            }
            }
            public int GetRoom(int room)
            {
                int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (room)
                {
                    case 1:
                        room1 += count;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        room2 += count;
                    case 3:
                        room3 += count;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        room4 += count;
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
        //This for statement lists the 4 rooms and their bottle count when the user has entered quit. An alternative to below
        /*for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", i + 1, rooms[i]);*/

      /*  int maxValue = 0;//initiates the winner, contructor starts at 0
        int maxRoomNumber = 0;//initiates the room number that wins
        for (int i = 0; i < room[i].Length; ++i)//This loop goes through the array of rooms (4)
        {
            if (room[i] > maxValue)//Makes sure that the maxValue is picked in the array
            {//Looking for room number for the  
                maxValue = room[i];
                maxRoomNumber = i + 1;
            }//Writes the bottles collected by the different rooms
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", i + 1, rooms[i]);
        }
        //Outputs winner
        Console.WriteLine("And the Winner is room " + maxRoomNumber + "!!!");
        */
    }
```

The last part of the program was my attempted to find max number, since i used an array to start. I must not use an array.

Comment: You need to move the room1, room2, room3 and room4 variables so that they are part of the class. You have them inside the main() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a Class to hold the information for each room. The reason for using a class is so that if your program needs to change in the future to collect more information, you won't have to track yet another array, you can just add properties to the class.

The individual rooms are now held in a list instead of an array just to show a different construct.

Here is the new Room class:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int BottleCount { get; set; }

    public Room(int wNumber)
    {
        Number = wNumber;
    }
}
```

And here is the new version of the program. Note that additional checking of the values entered by the end user has been added in order to prevent exceptions when trying to get the current room or parse to an int the value entered by the user:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int MAX_ROOMS = 4;
        var cRooms = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Room>();

        for (int nI = 0; nI < MAX_ROOMS; nI++)
        {
            // The room number is 1 to 4
            cRooms.Add(new Room(nI + 1));
        }

        // Initializes the room that wins
        //Start of while loop to ask what room your adding into. 
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
            //If user enters quit at anytime, the code will jump out of while statement and enter for loop below
            string roomNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            if (roomNumber == "quit")
            {
                //Break statement allows quit to jump out of loop
                break;
            }
            int room = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(roomNumber, out room) && (room < MAX_ROOMS) && (room >= 0)) {
                Room currentRoom;

                currentRoom = cRooms[room];

                Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", currentRoom.Number);

                int wBottleCount = 0;

                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out wBottleCount) && (wBottleCount >= 0))
                {
                    // This line adds the count of bottles and records it so you can continuously count the bottles collected.
                    currentRoom.BottleCount += wBottleCount;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid bottle count; value must be greater than 0");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid room number; value must be between 1 and " + MAX_ROOMS.ToString());
            }
        }

        Room maxRoom = null;

        foreach (Room currentRoom in cRooms) //This loop goes through the array of rooms (4)
        {
            // This assumes that the bottle count can never be decreased in a room
            if ((maxRoom == null) || (maxRoom.BottleCount < currentRoom.BottleCount))
            {
                maxRoom = currentRoom;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", currentRoom.Number, currentRoom.BottleCount);
        }
        //Outputs winner
        Console.WriteLine("And the Winner is room " + maxRoom.Number + "!!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the int declarations above the Main method like this :

```
class Program
{
     int room1 = 0;
     ....
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    ....
    }
}
```